# celerybeat - отказано в доступе

Tags: django, сервер, celery, celerybeat

Пытаюсь демонизировать celery beat.

При запуске `service celerybeat start` вылетает ошибка

```
env: /etc/init.d/celerybeat: Отказано в доступе
```

Причем если запускать вручную, то celery запускается

---

```
[root src]# cat /etc/systemd/system/celerybeat.service
[Unit]
Description=Celery Beat Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=myuser
Group=myuser
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery
#WorkingDirectory=/opt/celery
WorkingDirectory=/srv/<path_to_django_src>
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A ${CELERY_APP} beat  \
    --pidfile=${CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE} \
    --logfile=${CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}'
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/etc/init.d/celerybeat` взят из [репозитория celery](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/celery/celery/master/extra/generic-init.d/celerybeat)

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Заметил, что в `/etc/init.d/` некоторые файлы отмечены как исполняемые.

Вопрос был решен `chmod +x /etc/init.d/celerybeat`